# Proof via mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Suppose $f$ is differentiable with $f(0)=0$; $f'(x)<0$ for all $x<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. Prove $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

It's pretty clear to me that $f$ decreases until $0$ and then $f$ starts increasing and $0$ is a minimum, so $f(x)\geq 0$, but I don't know how to write it via $\textit{mean value theorem}$.

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!

Comment: If Nitin or I helped you answer your question you should click the checkmark next to one of our answers (it'll turn green once you do).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}{x},\quad c\in(0,x) \text{ and } x\gt 0$$ and $$f'(c) = \frac{f(0)-f(x)}{0-x} = \frac{f(x)}{x},\quad c\in(x,0) \text{ and } x\lt 0$$ separately.  What can you say about $f(x)$ in each of these cases?